# Weird behaviour when returning char.pop() inside .map()

Tags: javascript, if-statement

### Problem

I've created (or tried to create) a JS function that **reverses a string ignoring special characters**. The function **doesn't work when there are 2 consecutive special characters**.

### Code

I provide all the code necessary to reproduce the problem bellow. including some tests that you can run with `mocha`. **The second test fails.**

The **following code passes** the tests:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const reverseButNoSpecial = (str) => {
    const specialChars = /[^a-zA-Z ]/g;

    // create an array withOUT special chars
    const cleanArray = str.replace(specialChars, "").split('');

    // iterate over the original
    // replace each letter with a letter from the clean array,
    // leave the special chars
    return str.split('').map(char => {
        if (specialChars.test(char)) {
            return char;
        }
        // remove the last char from the reversed array
        const removed = cleanArray.pop();
        // return the char that was removed
        return removed;
    }).join('');
}

describe('Reverse all characters except special chars', () => {
    it ('should work for a,b$c!', () => {
        expected = 'c,b$a!';
        actual = reverseButNoSpecial('a,b$c!');
        assert.strictEqual(expected, actual);
    })

    it ('should work for Ab,c,d$$e!', () => {
        expected = 'ed,c,b$$A!';
        actual = reverseButNoSpecial('Ab,c,d$$e!');
        assert.strictEqual(expected, actual);
    })
})
```

### Expected vs Actual

Expected `reverseButNoSpecial('Ab,c,d$$e!')` to return `ed,c,b$$A!` but got `ed,c,b$A!`

(notice the `$` appears only once when it should appear twice `$$`

Can someone help me figure out why?

Comment: Hi. I rolled your question back to the revision before you added "Solved" to the start of the title and explained the solution at the start of the question. It's [not necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/284827) (and is discouraged) to put "solved" in your title when you have a solution as the site already has ways to display this (e.g. your question has a "1 with a solid green background to say that you have accepted an answer, the answer has a tick on it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 'gotcha' when re-using regular expression objects that search globally. The regular expression objects maintains state, specifically the lastIndex property remains unchanged.

Here's a good explanation:
https://siderite.dev/blog/careful-when-reusing-javascript-regexp.html

To fix, don't use a 'specialChars' object, just use the regular expression object raw, like this:

> (/[^a-zA-Z ]/g).test(char)

Comment: That is truly weird. In trying to figure out the bug in OP's apparently bug-free code I tried `'****'.split('').map(c => specialChars.test(c));` and was quite surprised when I saw `[ true, false, true, false ]`. This seems like a bug in the language rather than a feature. I can't think of a valid use-case for it. +1 for pointing it out.